# Does this building on chinese painting exist for real ? May the text which come along be of any help?

Tags: characters, character-identification, traditional-characters, literary-chinese, old-chinese

I am wondering if this building on a chinese painting is for real ? Or just if something close exists... it may be on an island and is rather cubic... I have nearly zero knowledge of chinese architecture.

The text put along side the drawing may help to know if it is pure fiction, so here it is. I also have zero knowledge of reading chineese too... so sorry.

The building

[image]

The text

[image]

The seal stamp 1

[image]

The seal stamp 2

[image]

The seal stamp 3

[image]

Thanks forward for your help !

Libel

PS. it might be so difficult to find out... I have really no clue of how hard it is and I really want to thank people who can give an hand...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the building exists, it’s called “turtle tower”, in hanoi, vietnam:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoàn_Kiếm_Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho%C3%A0n_Ki%E1%BA%BFm_Lake)

[image]

Comment: This is it... thanks a lot !