# Can anyone help identifying this chinese seal stamps on a painting?

Tags: translation, characters, traditional-characters, seal, literary-chinese

I am trying to identify three seal stamps. However I am rather unsuccessful...

There are the three that are on the painting :

[image]

[image]

[image]

If someone can help... I have to admit that it is really difficult and I have no clue...

Thanks forward !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 張路
2. 穆昕風/星昕風 (not sure)
3. 寄情 (奇崝?)

For #1 I am pretty sure since [in your another post](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/does-this-building-on-chinese-painting-exist-for-real-may-the-text-which-come) the full text can be read, 劍湖春曉甲戍新春初四日寫於河內**張路**, `Sword Lake's Spring morning, 甲戍, new year the fourth day (after), written in Hanoi by Zhang Lu', where I am not sure of the word 春, maybe 喜. Also FYI [劍湖](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho%C3%A0n_Ki%E1%BA%BFm_Lake) is the Sword Lake, and 河內 is Hanoi, and [甲戍](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%B2%E6%88%8C) is the year 1874, 1934, 1994, 2054, etc.

P.S. Good calligraphy and painting!

Comment: the first character of the third seal is “寄” (u+5bc4) 

Comment: Waouh ! I am so impressed ... and especially ashamed since my mom was born ... in **Hanoi**  ^^"
Thank you very much :)
I would not have been able to achieve such a result... I am so grateful ... hope the best !